# Dúvida em JavaScript ao criar divs dinâmicas

Tags: javascript, html

Eu fiz um código que adiciona um conjunto de campos dentro de um form, quando solicitado por meio de um botão, e alguns desses campos usam funções js para criar máscaras (para o CPF, rg, CEP), o problema está aí, essas funções de máscara deixam de funcionar nos campos gerados, sei muito pouco de JS então nem faço ideia do que pode ser..
Usei apenas 2 campos pra facilitar, observem que nos campos criados normalmente a função máscara funciona, e nos campos criados pela função, a máscara não funciona.

o plugin JS que utilizei: [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)

Página html já com as funções JS

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="_js/jquery.mask.js"></script>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
      $('.mixed').mask('00.000.000');
      $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
      $('.cep2').mask('00000-000');
      $('.dtIni').mask('00 SS SSSSSS SS 0000');
      $('.cnae').mask('00.00-0-00');
    });

    var qtdeCampos = 0;

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function addAdmin() {
        var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
        //Criando o elemento DIV;
        var objFilho = document.createElement("div");
        //Definindo atributos ao objFilho:
        objFilho.setAttribute("id","filho"+qtdeCampos);

        //Inserindo o elemento no pai:
        objPai.appendChild(objFilho);
        //Escrevendo algo no filho recém-criado:
        document.getElementById("filho"+qtdeCampos).innerHTML = "<br> 
         <label>Preencha os Dados:<label><br> <label>RG:</label> <input type='text' name='campoAdmin[]' class='mixed'  placeholder='Ex: 12.345.678' required autocomplete='off' size='10'> <label>CPF:</label> <input type='text' name='campoAdmin[]' class='cpf' size='13' placeholder='Ex: 123.456.789-16' required><br> <input type='button' onClick='removerAdmin("+qtdeCampos+")' value='Remover Administrador'>";
        qtdeCampos++;
    }

    function removerAdmin(id) {
        var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
        var objFilho = document.getElementById("filho"+id);

        //Removendo o DIV com id específico do nó-pai:
        var removido = objPai.removeChild(objFilho);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="form1" action="pegardados.php" method="post">
        <!--campos criados normalmente -->
        <label>Preencha os Dados:<label><br>
        <label>RG:</label> <input type='text' name='campoAdmin[]' class='mixed'  placeholder='Ex: 12.345.678' required autocomplete='off' size='10'> 
        <label>CPF:</label> 
        <input type='text' name='campoAdmin[]' class='cpf' size='13' placeholder='Ex: 123.456.789-16' required>

        <!--campos que serão criados pela função JS addAdmin() -->
        <div id="campoPai"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Adicionar campos" onclick="addAdmin()">
        <br><br><input type="submit" value="Enviar">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suas máscaras só são carregadas no `$(document).ready()` e seus elementos são inseridos após isso, você deve arrumar uma maneira de reaplicar essas máscaras após inserir um novo elemento na tela, creio que separando essas máscaras em uma função

```
function mascaras(){
    $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
    $('.mixed').mask('00.000.000');
    $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
    $('.cep2').mask('00000-000');
    $('.dtIni').mask('00 SS SSSSSS SS 0000');
    $('.cnae').mask('00.00-0-00');
}
```

carregando elas no `$(document).ready()` invocando a função

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    mascaras();
});
```

e aplicando a máscara novamente a cada elemento inserido

```
function addAdmin() {
    var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
    //Criando o elemento DIV;
    var objFilho = document.createElement("div");
    //Definindo atributos ao objFilho:
    objFilho.setAttribute("id","filho"+qtdeCampos);

    //Inserindo o elemento no pai:
    objPai.appendChild(objFilho);
    //Escrevendo algo no filho recém-criado:
    document.getElementById("filho"+qtdeCampos).innerHTML = "<br> 
     <label>Preencha os Dados:<label><br> <label>RG:</label> <input type='text' name='campoAdmin[]' class='mixed'  placeholder='Ex: 12.345.678' required autocomplete='off' size='10'> <label>CPF:</label> <input type='text' name='campoAdmin[]' class='cpf' size='13' placeholder='Ex: 123.456.789-16' required><br> <input type='button' onClick='removerAdmin("+qtdeCampos+")' value='Remover Administrador'>";
    qtdeCampos++;

    //invocando a função para reaplicar as máscaras aos elementos
    mascaras();
}
```

resolva o seu problema.

Comment: Caara, funcionou, nem acredito haha

Comment: Eu encontrei na documentação, que o innerHTML não executa scripts no HTML5, então pensei que não iria conseguir por causa de definições da linguagem, valeu mesmo pela ajuda, foi de grande valia.